# starting cron service fails with code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I just noticed that my server's cron service is not running.
I only have 1 script to run via cronjob and when I added it, it was not executing.
Already tried to execute the script manually and there was no issue with it.

Upon running **service cron status** I realized that the cron service was not running.
I tried running it to no avail.
Checked the status again found:

```
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-01-15 13:55:04 UTC; 5min ago
Docs: man:cron(8)
Process: 1127 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 1127 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 15 13:55:04 ip-172-31-8-42 systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Jan 15 13:55:04 ip-172-31-8-42 systemd[1]: cron.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 15 13:55:04 ip-172-31-8-42 systemd[1]: cron.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 15 13:55:04 ip-172-31-8-42 systemd[1]: cron.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please post the output of `ldd /usr/sbin/cron`.

Comment: The file: /usr/sbin/cron is missing.
I checked the other server with a working cron service and it has one.
While the one with the error does not have the said file.

Comment: I removed cron and it's dependencies from the server and reinstalled a new copy.
It is working now, however, I would still greatly appreciate it if someone could make me understand what happened. This way I could prevent it from happening again in the future

Comment: Someone deleted an important file, thinking it was not important.

Comment: @MichaelHampton
got the reason why, there was a malware on the system and the malware intentionally removed that important file to prevent me from editing the crontabs.
It was using the crontabs to execute itself.

Thanks for putting in that comment, it lead me to a correct path.
much appreciated!

Comment: @AndrewSchulman
Thanks for the edit!